# Why is MYSQL slow_query_log not enabled?

Tags: mysql, mysql-slow-query-log

I have the following in .my.cnf

```
# LOGGING #
slow_query_log                  = ON
slow_query_log_file             = /var/log/mariadb/slow_query.log
log-queries-not-using-indexes   = 1
```

When I run tuning-primer.sh I get this:

```
SLOW QUERIES
The slow query log is NOT enabled.
Current long_query_time = 10.000000 sec.
You have 0 out of 36 that take longer than 10.000000 sec. to complete
Your long_query_time seems to be fine
```

Can someone explain how is this possible?

Comment: Do lower long_query_time to 1 (or some other small value).

Comment: Were those settings in the `[mysqld]` section of `.my.cnf`?  Is `.my.cnf` actually being read?  (Changing `long_query_time` in it would apparently provide such a clue.)

Comment: +-----------------+----------+
| Variable_name   | Value    |
+-----------------+----------+
| long_query_time | 1.000000 |
+-----------------+----------+

Comment: Yes the settings are in [mysqld], what command do I use to see the current config in use?

Comment: `SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES;`  (from within the mysql commandline tool; UIs have some place to do arbitrary commands.)  It looks like you did that.

Comment: https://gist.github.com/highacid/395cdcf160a7662776e7 here are variables.

Comment: @RickJames any updates on this?

Comment: Does `/var/log/mariadb/slow_query.log` exist?  If not, does the 'user' mariadb or mysql have permissions to write to the directory `/var/log/mariadb`?  Does `SHOW GLOBAL STATUS` say any slow queries happened?  You could change `long_query_time` to 0 to catch all queries -- that would see if the cutoff of 1 was too high.

Comment: Can you dissect `tuning-primer.sh` to see how it checks for "NOT enabled"?

Comment: It seems that slow queries are working: Uptime: 215129  Threads: 3  Questions: 4368920  Slow queries: 159989  Opens: 1453  Flush tables: 1  Open tables: 1448  Queries per second avg: 20.308

Comment: Nearly 1/sec and 3% of queries -- that's high.  There are some other questions in the comments that you have not yet answered.

Comment: @RickJames I did not managed to find in tunner there and why is not detecting slow_query_log, yet I know is on due to 100 MB log file size. Not sure what to do about this.

Comment: If _you_ can find the slowlog, then _you_ can run `mysqldumpslow` or `pt-query-digest`.  Or you can simply look at the file (it is text).  Meanwhile, let's ignore that the 'tuner' could not find it.  (BTW, I posted a bug report against it mentioning 3 other errors in that part of the script.)

Comment: @RickJames I looked at the log, still I do not know what to do with this data... Its over 100 MB.

Comment: Use one of those tools to summarize it.  With the first one, use `-s t -t 5`; that will give the 5 "worst" queries.  5 is usually more than enough to work on optimizing.

Comment: https://gist.github.com/highacid/476d745c232349284b01 here is my feedback @RickJames

Answer (score 0):

Apparently the slowlog *is* working now.  Do you know what fixed that issue?

Meanwhile, this has morphed into query tuning...

What is #1 for?  Why is it run so often?  It returns an average of 156K rows examined (the whole table?), but only 665 rows returned.  665 is a lot of rows; do you really need them all?  Could more filtering be done in the SQL?

It sounds like there is no `INDEX(autoload)` -- add it; it should speed up the query considerably.

```
#1
SELECT  option_name, option_value
    FROM  wp_options
    WHERE  autoload = 'S'
```

What are you doing with the thousands of rows from the following?  And you are preforming them thousands of times?

```
#2
SELECT  st.value AS tra, s.value AS org, s.domain_name_context_md5 AS ctx
    FROM  wp_icl_strings s
    LEFT JOIN  wp_icl_string_translations st ON s.id=st.string_id
      AND  st.status=N
      AND  st.language='S'
      AND  s.language!='S'
#3
SELECT  slug, taxonomy
    FROM  wp_posts
    INNER JOIN  wp_term_relationships  ON (wp_posts.ID = wp_term_relationships.object_id)
    INNER JOIN  wp_term_taxonomy  ON (wp_term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id =
                                           wp_term_taxonomy.term_taxonomy_id )
    INNER JOIN  wp_terms ON (wp_term_taxonomy.term_id = wp_terms.term_id )
    WHERE  wp_posts.ID IN ("S","S","S","S","S","S","S","S","S",...)
    ORDER BY  wp_terms.name ASC 
#4
SELECT  t.element_id, tax.term_id, tax.taxonomy
    FROM  wp_icl_translations t
    JOIN  wp_term_taxonomy tax ON t.element_id = tax.term_taxonomy_id
      AND  t.element_type = CONCAT('S', tax.taxonomy)
    JOIN  wp_terms terms ON terms.term_id = tax.term_id
    WHERE  tax.term_id != tax.term_taxonomy_id
```

Why the `LEFT` in #2?  That probably prevents starting with `st`, which might be more selective with `INDEX(language, status)`.

In #3:  wp_terms might benefit from `INDEX(name)`.

In #4:  The schema design led to the clumsy `CONCAT('S', tax.taxonomy)`; can that be rectified?  That is, can `t.element_type` and `tax.taxonomy` look the same -- either both with the prefix or both without?  Or maybe the prefix is a separate column?

If you would like to discuss any of these further, please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` and `EXPLAIN SELECT ...`.

Comment: How do I run the SHOW CREATE TABLE and EXPLAIN SELECT? Do they need to be runned on a specific DB? Also how do I add Index(autoload). Thanks

Comment: Get familiar with one of these: `phpmyadmin`, `MySQL Workbench`, or mysql commandline tool.  WP does some nice things, but it isn't keeping you from learning a bunch about the underlying MySQL.

Comment: can you please tell me if MySQL Workbench can help me with enabling the INDEX,autoload?

Comment: "autoload" is not a MySQL term; please explain where it comes from and what it does.

Comment: INDEX(autoload) You mentioned this in the answer above.

Comment: Maybe the real question about #1 is "Why does WP need to load its options so often?" and "Why did they pick such a slow way to do it?".  Probably adding an index to wp_options would not help.

Comment: I had many transients I have cleaned @ 8000 lines of transients rows.